# Accessing private member of class in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have following code that can access and change private member outside the class

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int data;
public:
    Test() { data = 0; }
    int getData() { return data; }
};

int main()
{
    Test t;
    int* ptr = (int*)&t;
    *ptr = 10;
    cout << t.getData();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It is basically against encapsulation .. I wish to know why such a technique exist to access private members? how this is happening beneath .. please explain???

If such a technique is there what's the use of making a member private??

Comment: Casting is a way of telling the compiler "I'm going to do something silly, don't worry about it".  It's not to be encouraged...

Comment: Before 11, this was UB

Comment: So basically wait till nearly midnight before doing it?

Comment: @OP, in C++ you can't stop a programmer from sabotaging his program if he really wants to. You could make it slightly harder by having a pImpl idiom and only distributing your code in closed-source binary form  ...

Comment: @Paranaix It still is pure UB. Assuming trivial layout for a non-trivial type (due to the user-provided constructor) and violating strict aliasing by using incompatible pointer types are both textbook UB. Also, `conio`, LOL.

Answer (score 3):

**Because C++ protects against accident rather than deliberate circumvention (fraud)**.
Only hardware can protect against malicious use of a general-purpose language, and even that is hard to do in realistic systems.

Mentioned by Bjarne Stroustrup in his book "The C++ Programming Language".

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It doesn't work.

**Why "works"?**

The size of your object is 4 bytes (`cout << size(t);`), which is the size of the integer.
This is why this appears to work, when you say this `int* ptr = (int*)&t;`, you are saying that this 4 bytes of `t` will be 4 bytes of `int`.

**Beneath the code**

This class is a POD (ignoring the constructor) ([see more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure))

The function `int getData() { return data; }`, is inlined by the compiler (I'm not sure) so `return data` returns the value of `*ptr` not `data`.

Test it with `int getData() { cout << data; }` and you will that `ptr` never touch the value data. This is called undefined behavior.

If your class has this private members (example):

```
int foobar;
int data;
```

Then your `t` class has the size of 8 bytes, and when converting `t` to `int`, you're getting the first 4 bytes, which is the variable foobar ([see more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_%28computer_science%29)). And this line `cout << t.getData();` will return 0, which is the value specific in the constructor.

Comment: "This class is a POD (ignoring the constructor)" You can't just 'ignore the constructor'. [POD classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType), via their requirement to be [trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType), cannot have user-defined constructors. This class does. This class is not a POD. Moreover, accessing the member through a pointer-to-class violates the strict aliasing rule. I could probably find more problems, but why bother? Everything about that code screams UB and should be flamethrowered into oblivion.